# When is @OneToMany list populated in Play framework?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

The Play framework's [Yet Another Blog Engine example](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/guide2) has a Post class with children Comments:

```
// Post.java
// ... other fields, etc.
@OneToMany(mappedBy="post", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Comment> comments;
// ...
```

When data is populated by the .yml, everything seems to work fine:

```
// BasicTest.java
@Test
public void fullTest() {
    Fixtures.load("data.yml");
    // ...
    // Find the most recent post
    Post frontPost = Post.find("order by postedAt desc").first();
    assertNotNull(frontPost);
    // ...
    // Check that this post has two comments
    assertEquals(2, frontPost.comments.size()); // succeeds
}
```

But when I manually save a Post and some Comments to the database, the frontPost.comments field is empty:

```
@Test
public void myFullTest() {
    // Fixtures.load("data.yml");

    User u = new User("bob@gmail.com", "secret", "Bob").save();
    Post p = new Post(u, "About the model layer", "The model has a central position in a Play! application. It is the ...").save();

    Comment c1 = new Comment(p, "Guest", "You are right !").save();
    Comment c2 = new Comment(p, "Mike", "I knew that ...").save();

    // Find the most recent post
    Post frontPost = Post.find("order by postedAt desc").first();

    // This assertion fails as frontPost.comments is empty:
    // "Failure, expected:<2> but was <0>"
    assertEquals(2, frontPost.comments.size());
}
```

Why does this happen, and how can I make JPA populate the Post.comments field when saving the classes one by one?

Thanks all!

**Update:** the solution was to call JPA.em().clear() before the find(....) call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using bidirectional relationships in JPA, maintaining consistency between both sides of the relationship for in-memory objects is up to you.

I'm not sure how Play Framework implements `find()`, but if `frontPost` is the same instance as `p` (i.e. not a fresh instance constructed from database data), it's `comments` collection is certainly empty.

Comment: Thanks, I learned that I need to use JPA.em().clear() to clear the Hibernate cache and force the object to be retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be calling em.refresh(p) instead of clearing the *whole* persistence context and detaching all your other entities.

This does however involve querying the db, so Play implement a helper method later on in the tutorial which will update the in-memory entity after persisting the new comment to save you a trip.